# spring-security session is not invalidating properly on timeout

Tags: spring, grails

I'm using spring-security-core 2.0 in my grails 2.4.4 application. I limited my concurrent session access of a user to 1.
So the problem is after session timeout of 30 minutes I couldn't login with that username and password, it will throw the concurrent session maximum exceeded exception.
I'm doubtful that, on the session timeout my logout is not working properly so that session can still be active.

I'm a newbi to spring-security so can anyone tell me what to do?

Here I'm giving What are changes I have made in my code to limit the concurrent access.

> resources.groovy

```html
// Place your Spring DSL code here
/*beans = {
 messageSource(org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) { basename = "classpath:grails-app/src/resource_bundle" }
}*/

import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import com.custom.sessiontime.CustomSessionLogoutHandler

beans = { 
   
  sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)
  
  customSessionLogoutHandler(CustomSessionLogoutHandler,ref('sessionRegistry'))
  
  concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy,ref('sessionRegistry')){
   exceptionIfMaximumExceeded = true
   maximumSessions = 1
  }
  
  sessionFixationProtectionStrategy(SessionFixationProtectionStrategy){
   migrateSessionAttributes = true
   alwaysCreateSession = true
  }
  registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy(RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy,ref('sessionRegistry'))
  
  sessionAuthenticationStrategy(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy,[ref('concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy'),ref('sessionFixationProtectionStrategy'),ref('registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy')])

   }
```

> CustomSessionLogoutHandler

```html
package com.custom.sessiontime

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;

/**
 * {@link CustomSessionLogoutHandler} is in charge of removing the {@link SessionRegistry} upon logout. A
 * new {@link SessionRegistry} will then be generated by the framework upon the next request.
 *
 * @author Mohd Qusyairi
 * @since 0.1
 */
public final class CustomSessionLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {
    private final SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance
     * @param sessionRegistry the {@link SessionRegistry} to use
     */
    public CustomSessionLogoutHandler(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        Assert.notNull(sessionRegistry, "sessionRegistry cannot be null");
        this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the {@link SessionRegistry}
     *
     * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler#logout(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
     * javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,
     * org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
     */
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) {
        this.sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(request.getSession().getId());
    }
}
```

> Finally added below line to Config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames = ['customSessionLogoutHandler','securityContextLogoutHandler','rememberMeServices']
```

Comment: Logout is already handled no need for an additional `LoguotHandler` make sure you are registering the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` which is what triggers the registration and cleanup of new and expired sessions.

Comment: I'm having this trouble in grails...How do you register the HttpEventPublisher for the spring security plugin for grails?